# How to fit SVG to an element in html?

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to edit an HTML page and include some SVG files into circle elements already on page. The element non-edited:

```html
<a id="slider-1-slide-1-layer-6" class="rs-layer" href="https://twitter.com/" 
target="_blank" data-type="text" data-color="#f2f2f2" data-rsp_ch="on" 
data-xy="xo:180px,180px,85px,85px;y:b;yo:160px,160px,75px,75px;" data-text="w:normal;
s:30,30,13,13;l:25,25,11,11;a:center;" data-dim="w:60px,60px,28px,28px;
h:60px,60px,28px,28px;" data-vbility="t,t,f,t" data-padding="t:18,18,8,8;"
data-border="bor:60px,60px,60px,60px;" data-frame_0="y:50,50,23,23;"
data-frame_1="sp:1000;" data-frame_999="o:0;st:w;" 
style="z-index:11;background-color:#61ae71;font-family:Poppins;"
<i class="icon-twitter"></i>
</a>
```

I have tried adding:

```html
<img src="images/twitter.svg" alt="twitter"/>
```

Link to SVG file: http://svgur.com/s/6w3

When I add the above `<img>` tag, the icon shows on the page with a grey box shadow, and is outside the circle.

Below is the shadow and the position of the icon is outside the circle/dot.

[image]

How would I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this??.I'm not sure if I understood you right.

```css
.icon-twitter {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:url("https://svgshare.com/i/6w3.svg");
    background-color:green;
    }
```

```html
<a href="https://twitter.com/"><div href="https:www.twitter.com" class="icon-twitter">
</div></a>
```

Comment: Not exactly, but I think I might have an idea of what to change if I understand your answer correctly. Going to try it and report back.

Comment: cool let me know.

Comment: Hmm..didn't work. I will add some images to explain better.

Comment: ok, i'll look at it again

Comment: Just changed it. Thank you for helping out a noob.

Comment: you need to make the background as that svg on that particular div. or if you can paste the code of the green div you have i'll be able to help you more specifically. look at my sample above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243773/discussion-between-crystal-and-sid).